# How to deactivate check boxes in one form in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

There are some certain check boxes in my OpenERP project which I don't want to keep there. Actually  I don't want any selection happen there. Please tell me how to deactivate those checkboxes or hide them from the form.

to the image

https://www.mediafire.com/?ul5ftyy233727qj

Comment: what code you do? please put a code

Comment: actually that's what I can't find out, I just need general idea...(I know it sound stupid but this is my first time with OERP )

Comment: I think you can't do that, like that is how a many2many works

Comment: oh... so that means I even can't hide those entire record set from the view right... ???